# only apply date format to date columns with xlwt

Tags: python-2.7, export-to-excel, xlwt

I have results from a database search where some columns have dates, but not others. I need help to write

```
data = [['556644', 'Mr', 'So', 'And', 'So', Decimal('0.0000'), datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 25, 0, 0), '', False, datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 30, 0, 0)],...]
```

into an Excel spreadsheet so that

```
easyxf(num_format_str='DD/MM/YYYY')
```

is only applied to the datetime columns. I'm quite new to Python and I've been banging my head on this for quite a few days now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After simplifying your self-answer:

```
date_xf = easyxf(num_format_str='DD/MM/YYYY') # sets date format in Excel
data = [list(n) for n in cursor.fetchall()]
for row_index, row_contents in enumerate(data):
    for column_index, cell_value in enumerate(row_contents):
        if isinstance(cell_value, datetime.date):
            sheet1.write(row_index+1, column_index, cell_value, date_xf)
        else:
            sheet1.write(row_index+1, column_index, cell_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is being imported from the SQL server with pyodbc, so that's from where cursor.fetchall() is coming:

```
data = [list(n) for n in cursor.fetchall()]
for row_index, row_contents in enumerate(data):
    for column_index, cell_value in enumerate(row_contents):
        xf=None
        if isinstance(data[row_index][column_index], datetime.date):
            xf = easyxf(num_format_str='DD/MM/YYYY') # sets date format in Excel
        if xf:
            sheet1.write(row_index+1, column_index, cell_value, xf)
        else:
            sheet1.write(row_index+1, column_index, cell_value)
```

Done! :)

Answer (score 0):

Want to write a date to a cell in Excel:

Add an extra attribute to the write call - the style for the cell:

```
import datetime
import xlwt

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')
date_style = xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='YYYY/MM/DD')
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Today')
worksheet.write(1, 0, datetime.date.today(), date_style)
workbook.save('C:\\data.xls')
```